# Is there an OCaml equivalent of npx?

Tags: package, ocaml

When using **node.js** we have `npx` - a tool that makes it easy for users to install and manage *applications* (especially CLI tools) rather than *libraries*. For Python there is `pipx`. Is there a tool for OCaml that offers the same functionality?

1. `pipx run "$APP" --example foo"` install & update & run all-in-one
2. Apps are installed into isolated environments so that they do not step on each other's toes. (e.g. incompatible dependency requirements)

I know there is one general-purpose option - Docker, but is there anything tailored to OCaml?

**Edit:** the main reason I dislike Docker is that it alters my view of the filesystem. A CLI tool might accept paths via the arguments, the environment and config files and then open them. Reading relative to CWD is also common. If a CLI tool is distributed via Docker, the user has to be aware of the altered filesystem view, which adds cognitive overhead.

Answer (score 1):

If you browse the list of [OPAM packages](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/), you will see not only libraries, but *also* applications. A few examples from a quick perusal:

- dune
- dumpast
- utop
- xe

Comment: I am not asking "Are there applications on OPAM"? Of course there are. I am asking "Is there a convenient tool to install them, run them and keep them up to date?"

Comment: opam is the tool that installs them and keeps them up to date. You don't need a tool to run them, they're binaries. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I am new to OCaml, but isn't a "switch" basically the equivalent of say pyenv+virtualenv for opam? https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Usage.html#opam-switch i.e. each switch has a specific ocaml compiler version and an isolated set of installed packages. Seems like outside of a switch opam is installing everything globally against default version. Wouldn't that mean that in theory you could ask it to install multiple packages with conflicting dependency requirements, and it would either refuse or would be unable to compile the binaries? I don't think there is an equivalent of npx/pipx.

Comment: The package dependencies within one switch need to be consistent. Each switch is independent though - there is no global repository, the active switch is only special in the sense that it is easier to access (its binaries are in the path).

Comment: Yes, so switch is like the pyenv+virtualenv combination in Python. A hypothetical "opamx" analogous to npx/pipx would take this a step further, being a tool to install ocaml apps apparently globally (linked into your path without having to manually activate an env), but still each within their own dedicated switch.